# Rails - Using Javascript on nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to integrate a sticky nav bar into a Rails app and I can't get the Javascript to work. I have seen similar questions, but none of them address this issue as I'm sure it's pretty elementary.

See the demo at: http://codepen.io/Guilh/details/JLKbn/

I have the following HTML in my `_header.html.erb` file:

```
<header>
  <h1>This is a Sticky Nav Demo!</h1>
  <p>Creating one of these isn't so bad. Let's learn how with this sweet little demo!</p>
</header>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <a href="#">Nav Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

The `Javascript/jQuery` is:

```
var  mn = $(".main-nav");
mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```

My `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I put the `Javascript` in the `Asset Pipeline` at `assets/javascript`. I am not very good with `js` and am not exactly sure how to call it. I tried wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function(){};`. I also tried putting it in `<script>` tags in the `_header.html.erb` file itself.

Comment: ` I can't get the Javascript to work`. what do you mean? what error did you get ? If possible provide a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using all of the required JavaScript files for this program? For example did you add this script to your html file?

```
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

When you go to the demo page right click it and go to view source copy and paste that code. It should work as an html file. I hope I am understanding you correctly.